# How to evaluate integrals of complex valued functions of a real variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(1-i)x^2} dx$, without invoking some sort of complex integral identify such as erf (ie as elementarily as possible)

I'm thinking to solve this similarly to solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x^2} dx$, where we can call in a second variable $y$, convert to polar, and take the square root of the result to get $\sqrt \pi$.

My attempt at this is to consider $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(1-i)(x^2+y^2)} dxdy = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{(1-i)(-r^2)} d\theta dr$. Normally, as in the case of $e^{-x^2}$, the limit is easy to compute, and we simply get something in terms of area of the unit circle. However, in this case, I'm not sure what to do with the imaginary term.

Am I on the right track? How can I continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should not suggest to use polar coordinates.

Consider instead
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax^2} \,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{a}} \quad \text{if} \quad \Re(a) >0$$
$$a=1-i \implies I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{1-i}}=\sqrt{1+i}\,\sqrt{\frac \pi 2}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not really sure where you got that formula. I was asked to use polar coordinates, and so I wanted to mimic the proof of $e^{-x^2}$, using polar coordinates so that I don't invoke any properties of "special functions".

Comment: @noHopeLeft. Just do the same